# ValueError when converting a string to dict:dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string to a dictionary but I keep getting this error:
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`
Here's my code:

```
string = r'{"extra":[{"text":"Hello World"}]}'
json_data = dict(string)
```

Comment: You can't just load a JSON text just like that. You need the json parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html (particularly the `loads` function to decode the string into a Python `dict`)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for:

```
import json
string = r'{"extra":[{"text":"Hello World"}]}'
json_data = json.loads(string)
```

There are a few JSON parsing libraries. Default one should suffice, simplejson is another option (just to give you an alternative).